# How to get the position of the imported Mesh from Assimp

Tags: c++, assimp

I am importing FBX files using assimp and also want to get the Transformation of the mesh from the model.

This is the function that gets the position of the mesh.

This works but sometimes the application crashes while importing certain models and if i remove the transformation part than  model imports successfully.

```
void processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene *scene)
{
    // process each mesh located at the current node
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];    
        ai_real x = scene->mRootNode->mChildren[iModel]->mTransformation.a4;
        ai_real y = scene->mRootNode->mChildren[iModel]->mTransformation.b4;
        ai_real z = scene->mRootNode->mChildren[iModel]->mTransformation.c4;        
        std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z; // if i comment this than no crash    
     }
}
```

Comment: `iModel` is undefined within your code snippet. It should be `node->mTransformation` I guess.

Comment: @gkv311 Thank you indeed that was the issue though i had given the iModel a value and was also incrementing it.

Comment: But that was not the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the instance of aiNode where the mesh is referenced and perform the whole transformation chain from your node up to the root node. The you can extract the position out of it. So in short:

1. Check if your node has any parent node.
2. If yes, get the transformation node from the parent, get its transformation and multiply this with your child transformation
3. Repeat this until you have reached the root node (parent pointer will be nullptr to find it)

With this global transformation you have the information where your mesh is located in the World-Space.

Comment: But how do you get the information of where your mesh is? I can see that we get a matrix but I don't quite understand how to derive the position from it.

Comment: The mesh is assigned to a iaNode instance. Each node have its local transformation matrix. Multiplying all local transformations until you reached the root of your node you will get the global transformation matrix fro you mesh. Keep in mind: this global transformation will describe the global position in relation to your imported aiScene instance.